# Translating normal code to 3AC - Three address code

Tags: python, algorithm, transcription

I am trying to make an algorithm that will transcribe certain input, such as:

```
(a * b) / (c * d)
```

and will print out input like this in [3AC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three-address_code):

```
t1: a * b
t2: c * d
t3= t1/t2
```

Has anyone any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Algorithm for transcribing such equations is pretty straightforward.

Obviously first task would be to convert given equation to [reverse polish notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_Polish_notation). From here you already have perfectly defined order of execution.

You now have to prepare stack for operands. At this point you just do it like normal RPN, except instead of performing operation and putting result back on operands stack, you have to print new TAC instruction with new number, and put that symbol back on stack instead of result.

In your example RPN will be : `a b * c d * /`

So `a` and `b` go on the stack. When we encounter `*` we pop 2 items from stack, print `t1 := a * b` and put `t1` on stack. Now we traverse RPN more and put `c` and `d` on stack. Now we come to encounter another `*`, so again lets pop 2 items from stack, print them with new TAC symbol `t2 := c * d` and put our new symbol `t2` back on stack.

lastly we encounter `/` so again we pop 2 items from stack, create new symbol and print it :) `t3 := t1 / t2`.

This is much simpler than standard RPN calculator.

Answer (score 0):

One way you could do this is to first turn this into an [AST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_syntax_tree)

then traverse the AST by recursive function to make your code.
for your example your code will be turned into something like this
`("/", ("*", "a", "b"), ("*", "c", "d")`
traverse with said function and turn it into this

```
t0 = a * b
t1 = c * d
t2 = t0 / t1
```